# Specifying default integer size for the Intel Fortran Compiler in CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, fortran, intel-fortran

I have a Fortran project which is setup with CMake, and on Windows I create a Visual Studio project for development. In the Visual Studio Project Property Pages window for my project, shown below, I want to specify the `Default Integer KIND` parameter to 8. In this same window it says that specifying `integer_size 64` should do the trick, but when I try to add `add_definitions("-integer_size 64")` or `set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "-integer_size 64")` in my `CMakeLists.txt`, the value in the Project Property Pages window does not change, so it appears to have to effect.

Anyone know what I have to do in CMakeLists.txt to make sure that the Default Integer KIND parameter shown in the window below is set to 8?

PS: I have also tried `add_definitions("-integer_size:64")` and `set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "-integer_size:64")`

[image]

Comment: That's a typo by me when creating the question, will edit it to say 64 instead of 32. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try the shorter `-i8`?

Comment: It doesn't change the value in the VS window but the compiler doesn't complain in anyway. I tried to add `-r8` because I need this for the Real as well, but then the compiler complained about `/r8` being an unknown option

Comment: Why do you use `-` in CMake and `/` elsewhere?

Comment: You can use `-` in CMake but when the fortran compiler complains it presents it with `/`. It seems like the `-` gets changed to `/` at some point, either by CMake when creating the VS project or by the intel fortran compiler. Anyways it seems like using `add_definitions("-i8" "-real_size:64")` works, however, it does not change the values in the VS window, but the flags are still sent to the fortran compiler.

Comment: Why would you expect it to affect the VS window in any way? Is cmake integrated into VS?

Comment: Because it affects other things like: Output directory, Target Name, Configuration Type, etc.